rasterio ImportError when calling osmnx add_node_elevations_raster() function
I am trying to run the example given in Notebook 12 of the osmnx-examples GitHub repo.
I used the provided environment.yml with conda to set up my environment:
conda env create -f environment.yml 

When I try to run this code block:
raster_path = "./input_data/elevation1.tif"
G = ox.elevation.add_node_elevations_raster(G, raster_path, cpus=1)

I get the error
ImportError: rasterio must be installed as an optional dependency to query rasters.
I have tried including rasterio and gdal in the environment yaml, but it I still get the same error message. I have also tried much Googling for solutions but have not found any.

The documentation says it depends on C libraries like gdal. Did you install that?

Yes I did install gdal

There's a bug we fixed recently where you'd get that error message if the rio_vrt package is not installed. Try installing that and it may fix it.
